# Angular 5 / Typings - Casting a service breaks access to properties

Tags: angular, typescript, casting, static

I've a strange problem with Angular ; I wrote a little service :

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()

export class HtmlService {
  public static keys(object: {}) {
    return Object.keys(object);
  }
}
```

I want to use the **keys** method in a template, so in the controller I inject it like this :

```
import {HtmlService} from "../../services/html.service";

export class PageComponent implements OnInit {

  public HtmlService: any = HtmlService;

  // [...]    
}
```

And the call in the template :

```
<ul *ngIf="HtmlService.keys(params).length > 0;else no_params">
```

I want to avoid **any** cast, so I try with :

```
public HtmlService: HtmlService = HtmlService;
```

And now I cannot access to **keys** method in the template :/

> Static member is not accessible

Why ? Is there another cast to write ?

Thanks !

---

**Edit**

From another answer that was deleted, I don't want to declare the method as dynamic because it's not. I already have a working example, I want to have a **clean** example. And, btw, learn why it doesn't work like this :)

Comment: Why do you use static method in your service?

Comment: Hmm.. Why not ? It's static because it's not dynamic. The service is a collection of functionality used in the templates

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to declare it inside of your `controller` at all, all you need to do is `import` it and use it as `HtmlService.<method>`

EDIT: Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/oUukit0K2M8QkVVbMpan?p=preview) example so we can get the confusion out, [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/oUukit0K2M8QkVVbMpan?p=preview) you can see a working example with `public HtmlService: HtmlService = HtmlService;`

Comment: If I do that it's not available in the template

Comment: Have you included it inside of your `module` and `injected` it through constructor inside of your `controller`? If not, I will update my code with a full example then, but it looks to me like you didn't since it's not available inside of a template

Comment: @NgModule({
      providers: [
        HtmlService
      ],
      // [...]
    }) So yes, but I don't inject it in the controller's constructor because I don't want an instance, I want the object to call the static method

Comment: inject it inside controller like this `constructor(private HtmlService: HtmlService)`

Comment: First, "public" otherwise the property is not accessible; and second, a static method cannot be accessed from an instanciated class...

Comment: have you even tried removing your `public HtmlService: HtmlService = HtmlService` and injecting it as I suggested through `constructor`?

Comment: Yes, immediatly after your comment ;) I try all suggestions before answering :)

Comment: When you inject the service you inject its instance not the constructor function. When you inject a the service like this `constructor(private htmlService: HtmlService)` you can access the constructor and the static methods like this `htmlService.constructor.keys()`. Not sure why you need a static method though, Angular makes sure that it's always the same instance that is injected.

Comment: So ugly. I understand what you said, about the "singleton way of life" of Angular. But this is not the question here. I just want somebody explain to me why it works when I cast it "any" and not "HtmlService".

Comment: It works even when you cast it to `HtmlService`, check the `second` plunker

Comment: What the hell.. It only fail when I build with "ng build --target=production" oO